# Can I use Kafka with Apache Camel as a replacement of ActiveMQ?

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-kafka, apache-camel

I have a Camel application that I build with Spring Boot. This app uses ActiveMQ to pass messages between two systems. Now I have a requirement to add the ability to chose, based on a configuration, between ActiveMQ and Apache Kakfa as the message brokers.

Is that something that can be done ? I have zero knowledge about Kafka, but for what I have being reading it doesn't work the same way as ActiveMQ.

Let's say that my Camel app publishes a message to a queue like this:

```
from("direct:inbound")
     //random stuff happening
    .to(ExchangePattern.InOnly, "jms:queue:custom-queue")
```

And I have in my **application.yml** this configuration

```
spring:
  activemq:
    packages:
      trusted:
      - java.util
      - java.lang
    broker-url: tcp://localhost:61616
```

Can I just replace the activemq configuration with Kafka specific configs and expect that it will magically work ? That's what my PM expects, at least.

Comment: Producing messages should work similarly, but consumer logic will need more updates, for sure

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Spring Cloud](https://spring.io/projects/spring-cloud-stream) does this. Various messaging systems can be used just by adding the specific binder.

A starting point would be to **create "adapter routes"** for ActiveMQ and Kafka and **conditionally create them** based on the configuration present.

These **adapter routes must handle all messaging system specific stuff** so that the "main routes" don't need to care about that (i.e. [hexagon architecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexagonal_architecture_(software))).

- Your core logic is in "main routes" who use `direct` endpoints
- There is an ActiveMQ consumer that forwards to the main routes
- There is a Kafka consumer that forwards to the main routes
- There is an ActiveMQ producer that produces messages received from the main routes
- There is a Kafka producer that produces messages received from the main routes
- The main routes send messages to the active producer, for example by using the [Recepient List EIP](https://camel.apache.org/components/latest/eips/recipientList-eip.html)

However, **ActiveMQ and Kafka are very different**. If you really want to take this route it could get very bumpy :-)